# Single autocomplete extender or plugin for more than one type of search?

Tags: jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I have used the ASP.Net AJAXT Toolkit Autocomplete extender before and I am currently looking at jQuery plugins that handle the same task. I need to find a way to do different type of searches with the same textbox control. The search page of this application has 4 options for search by things like - name - account number - zip code - etc. So I want to change the page method or web method that the extender or plugin uses depending on which radio button is selected. I am not finding any examples of this - only examples of separate textboxes with separate extenders pointing to different page or web methods. Has anyone seen an example of something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the jqueryui autocomplete.

I put together a quick crude demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8zy44/

Instead of changing the source to a local variable you can also specify a url for the source.

Comment: Nice - not exactly what I was looking for but close enough to show me how to do what I need - I'll give it a shot and if it works I'll mark this as the answer - thanks.